# What would crontab do if the server is shutdown?

Tags: shell, cron

Say I have a crontab like:

`*/30 * * * * /root/scripts/remove_log_files.sh`

This will remove some logs that I don't want every 30 mins.

What would happen if the server shutdown after 25 mins the crontab is activated and restarted 10 mins later?

Update: according to some searches the job will not be fired. But will the job be delayed another 30 mins to be executed or 25 mins?

Couldn't find some resource discussing this online. Most of the discussion is about how to shutdown a machine with crontab.

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/390036/what-happens-to-cron-jobs-when-the-system-is-down, http://serverfault.com/questions/52335/job-scheduling-using-crontab-what-will-happen-when-computer-is-shutdown-during (try searching for `cron missed jobs`)

Comment: thanks, I think the missed job won't run when the system is restarted but a detail is still not clear: will it be executed after another 30 mins or after another 25 mins? (I'm using bash on my Macintosh)

Comment: isn't `*/30` a shortcut to `0,30` and `*/15` a shortcut to `0,15,30,45` etc ...

Comment: oh... I think I figured it out. My stupid.

Comment: It `*/30` does not cause a syntax error message, then you are not running cron but a surrogate and need to check the behavior of this specific implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional `cron` checks every minute if the current time matches one of the time pattern in the `crontab` and executes every matched lines. There is no notion of "missed jobs" or "jobs running soon" at all. The pattern

```
*/30 * * * *
```

matches on timestamps with minutes dividable by 30 (that is 0 and 30).

If you want something like "run every 25 minuts of system uptime" you need a more modern `cron` implementation.
One of them is `fcron`, which adds lots of extra ways to describe when to run jobs, including the very useful "don't run two of these jobs simultanuously", something traditional `cron` isn't capable of.